# access violation when resizing bytes field in DEBUG mode

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have the following message definition

```
syntax = "proto3";

message TestMessage {
  fixed32 id = 1;
  bytes data = 2;
}
```

When I run the following program in DEBUG mode, I get an access violation.

```
#include <cstdint>                       
#include "test.pb.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestMessage msg;
    msg.set_id(4711);
    std::string* dataString = msg.mutable_data();
    dataString->resize(100000); // access violation here

    std::cout << (*dataString) << std::endl;    

    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

}
```

Even the following throws an access violation in DEBUG mode.

```
#include <cstdint>                       
#include "test.pb.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestMessage msg;
    msg.set_id(4711);
    std::string* dataString = msg.mutable_data();
    dataString->append("Hello, World!");
    dataString->append("Hello, World!");
    dataString->append("Hello, World!"); // access violation here
    dataString->append("Hello, World!");     

    std::cout << (*dataString) << std::endl;    

    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

}
```

In RELEASE mode the programs work as expected.

It’s annoying, as I cannot test my real app in DEBUG mode.

Any ideas what the problem is?

(Environment: Windows 10, Protocol Buffers v3.6.1, VS 2017, via cmake)

(`#define PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS` added to test.pb.h)

EDIT:

I tried again with static linked libs instead of dymanic linked, and than it works also in DEBUG mode.

Comment: Likely that the `std::string* dataString = msg.mutable_data();` which is a pointer to a string, is pointing to a string that has gone out of scope in `msg.mutable_data()` and no longer exists.

Comment: I tried looking around sources from the generated code and libproto, but could not find anything obvious. I would suggest running your program with gdb, and find the exact point the error occurs as well as the stack of functions called. Since the error happens in DEBUG, the location of the error will probably include lines in the source code.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I tried again with static linked libs instead of dynamic linked, and than it works also in DEBUG mode. So I'm can work again, but I'm still curious why it is not working with DLLs

Comment: My psychic powers suggest that the result from `msg.mutable_data()` is NULL (nullptr).

Comment: @selbie that was my first thought, but turns out that pb3.6 initializes defaults so the return is fine, but the alloc is happening in the protobuf lib which he is linking dynamically to... ergo my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible CRT/heap mismatch. Build protobuf in debug (link against debug VCRT) and link in protobuf itslef statically (as recommended in the docs) with your debug build.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries?view=vs-2017

Comment: OK, this could be the problem. It works as statically linked.